# Alert Dialog with an option to request the email verification link from firebase is not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to show an alert dialog with two buttons ("OK" and "Send Email") in user login activity. I am using firebase for user authentication. Before trying to implement alert dialog, I used `Toast.makeText` to show that email address is not verified and I was working perfectly fine. But now I want to give user an option to request the email verification link again in case they couldn't find the previous one. I went through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html and also went through some questions and answers on slackoverflow. The problem I am facing here is even though I can make the dialog popup by making a fragment class, I can't use this option. Because I don't know a way to retrieve current user instance from firebase to another class. It always crushes the app if I try to do it that way. So, I tried to implement alert dialog in the activity class and you can see my code below.

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if (!user.isEmailVerified()){

                            AlertDialog.Builder emailAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            emailAlert.setTitle("Verify you email");
                            emailAlert.setMessage("The email address is not verified.");
                            emailAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                            emailAlert.setNegativeButton(R.string.send_email, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    user.sendEmailVerification()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });


                            emailAlert.create();
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));

                    }

                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed, please make sure all feids are complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

There is no run time error but the alert dialog is not showing up. Can someone please point me out what I am doing wrong? And please let me know if there is a better way to get the same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all replace

> AlertDialog.Builder emailAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

with

> AlertDialog.Builder emailAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Because getActivity() will not work for Activity.

And the main thing is that replace

> emailAlert.create();

with

> emailAlert.show();

Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Pleasure is mine. Thanks.